# The biholomorphic structure of Torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We know that the tours  can be viewed as $\mathbb C/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is the lattice in the complex plane.

**Question**: Why the Biholomorphic Mapping Group of Torus is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, i.e. two tori $\mathbb C/\Lambda$, $\mathbb C/\Lambda'$ are biholomorphic to each other, iff $\exists f\in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ s.t. $f(\Lambda)=\Lambda'$.

Thanks.

Comment: What you said doesn't make sense--you asked why the biholomorphic structure on a torus (which makes sense--it's a complex manifold) is the same as that on $\SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which is not a complex manifold. Can you recheck your question?

Comment: I guess you have to say that $z \mapsto z+1$ and $z \mapsto -1/z$ generate your group, but I'm not sure how @AlexYoucis

Comment: @user1952009 The user has since changed the question. Now it sounds like they're asking for the set of self-biholomorphisms of the torus. This is precisely $(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda)\rtimes \text{Aut}((\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,0))$ where the first is just the points of the torus acting by translation, and the latter is a finite group of self-group-biholomorphisms (of which there can be at most 6 if I'm not misremembering the numerology of it). I don't see where $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ comes into play. The usual suspect would be that $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$

Comment: is isomorphic (as an elliptic curve--so preserving base point) to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda'$ if and only if $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ differ by an $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-action. Is that what you meant OP?

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you for the explanation. But this just shows that $SL_2(\mathbb Z)\subset BiHol(T^2)$. How to show the converse?

Comment: @ DLIN What I wrote is a nonsense. The [elliptic curve corresponding to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Differential_equation) is $E_\Lambda = \{(x,y), y^2 = 4 x^3-g_2(\Lambda)x-g_3(\Lambda) \}$. So what @AlexYoucis wrote suggest to look at $E_{\Lambda'}$ where $\Lambda' = \gamma. \Lambda$ for some $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Now it is not clear to me why $E_\Lambda \simeq  E_{\Lambda'}$

Answer (score 0):

Let lattice $\Lambda$ be generated by two complex numbers $f_1$ and $f_2$. We need $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, so $f_2/f_1$ can't be a real number, because in this case $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}$. By dividing over $f_1$ we can assume without loss of generality that $f_1=1$ and $f_2$ is in the upper half plane (it is not real, if it is in the lower half-plane we just choose another generator in the upper half plane). So we parameterized all curves by points in the upper half-plane.

We can choose a different basis of $\Lambda$ of the same form $\{1,f_2'\}$, it is related to the given basis by an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. And the torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ does not depend on which basis we choose.

The lattices $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ give the same curve if and only if there is a non-zero complex number $t$ s.t. $\Lambda=t\Lambda'$. So, the center $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts trivially and we get isomorphic curves if and only if $\Lambda' = f(\Lambda)$, where $f \in PGL_2(\mathbb{R})=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $f$ changes the basis.